# GSTreamer audio/video synchronization over RTP

Tags: synchronization, gstreamer, rtp, alsa, v4l2

I am trying to record a microphone from one PC and send it ove RTP to a laptop on a local network, and record video from another PC and send it to the same laptop, also over RTP. This part is fairly simple, and I have:

Sending video:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.14 port=5000
```

Sending audio:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v alsasrc ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,channels=1 ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,rate=48000 ! rtpL24pay ! udpsink host=192.168.0.14 port=5001
```

The receiver on the laptop is what I am struggling with. What I want is to take the audio and the video streams, synchronize them and produce an output mp4 (or any other format) video file. What I have for now is:

`gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtpjitterbuffer drop-on-latency=true latency=200 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! queue ! mux. udpsrc port=5001 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)48000, encoding-name=(string)L24" ! rtpjitterbuffer  drop-on-latency=true latency=200 ! rtpL24depay ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! lamemp3enc ! queue ! mux. mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location=output.mp4`

This produces a single output file, but the video and audio are not synchronized. I read that I need to use the same rtpjitterbuffer element, but when I try to give the rtpjitterbuffer name and use it again, I either get that jitter0 element does not exist, or that I can not connect it.

`gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H264" ! rtpjitterbuffer name=jitter0 drop-on-latency=true latency=40 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! queue ! mux. udpsrc port=5001 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)audio, clock-rate=(int)48000, encoding-name=(string)L24" ! rtpjitterbuffer name=jitter0 ! rtpL24depay ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! lamemp3enc ! queue ! mux. mp4mux name=mux ! filesink location=output.mp4`

Can you help me, how to fix this?

I tryied to use the same rtpjitter element, but I don't know how to do it, I also don't know if this is the way to go.

Comment: how is this supposed to work? Is the assumption that both producer PCs have perfectly synchronized clocks, such that frames could be synched by timestamp?

Comment: Let's assume. I have moved everything to a single machine and sending on localhost for now, and the problem is identical as before. There is about 20s delay between video and audio. 

I have also tried moving everything to a python script and setting the pipeline.set_base_time(0)
pipeline.set_start_time(Gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE) 
but the delay still persists. I am trying to solve first this problem and then I will worry about the device clock.

Comment: Have you tried adding `do-timestamp=true` to both sources?

Comment: added now, but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting the same SSRC in your rtp...pay elements. This is supposed to hint the receiver they are coming from the same source and should be synchronized.